# Is it necessary to use namespaces as per PHP's PSR-1 coding standard?

Tags: php, psr-1

I am new to following the coding standard PSR for PHP, specifically conforming to [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/). Now I am confused about one thing.

That is, **is it necessary to use namespaces as per the PSR-1 standard?** There's no explicit mention of the fact that it's a MUST to use them.

Also, let's suppose I have the following code in a single file:

```
<?php

class A
{}

class B extends A
{}

class C extends A
{}
```

Based on the PSR-1 standard (and its mention of namespaces and classes), is this code OK, or do I have to create a separate file for each class, along with a separate namespace for each file?

Comment: Perhaps look at PSR 4 for an approach to namespaces and files.

Comment: Having them in a single file is useful for PSR-4, specially if you plan on making this available via composer later down the line

Comment: PHP Code Sniffer will report all PSR-1, PSR-2 or PSR-12 issues automatically https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer

Comment: Attn close voters: this question is about compliance with a published standard; it is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: PSR-1 also explains how to format class constants, but that doesn't mean it is necessary to use class constants.